# SQL Server: Insert Result of WHOAMI into Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 2 columns, one of which I would like to insert the result of the `WHOAMI` command. Tried doing the following but I presume it won't work due to the different amount of columns:

```
UPDATE tblName 
SET colName = (xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe') 
WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Value VARCHAR(8000))

INSERT INTO @t
EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell 'whoami'

UPDATE tblName
SET colName =
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) Value
        FROM @t
        WHERE Value IS NOT NULL
    )            
WHERE id = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the user who's logged into the database (which could be a Windows or a SQL Login), you could use the built in `SUSER_NAME()` function instead

```
UPDATE tblName set colName = SUSER_NAME() WHERE id=1
```

If you truly want the service account that's running the SQL Server process (which is what you'd get from `whoami.exe`), you may be better off using the `sys.dm_server_services` view, which won't require enabling `xp_cmdshell` (which can pose some security risks if it's not locked down properly) (note: this requires SQL Server 2008R2 SP1 at a minimum):

```
UPDATE tblName 
SET colName = (
    SELECT TOP 1 
       service_account 
    FROM sys.dm_server_services 
    WHERE servicename LIKE 'SQL Server (%') 
WHERE id=1
```

otherwise

```
DECLARE @output TABLE (v varchar(200))

INSERT @output (v) exec xp_cmdshell 'whoami.exe'

UPDATE tblName SET colName = (select top 1 * from @output) WHERE id=1
```

Comment: SUSER_NAME() only brings back sa rather than all the columns

Comment: It'd give you the current user rather than the service account that's running SQL Server.  Going to update.

Comment: @pee2pee, I've updated my answer a bit to give you a couple other options.  I would personally go for the `dm_server_services` view just because I don't generally like to worry about xp_cmdshell being involved in anything.

Comment: Thanks the `sys.dm_server_services`